# T-SQL script to update numerous prod tables from temp tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to simplify the updating of numerous production tables from temp tables.  I currently have a long script that uses the MERGE command, but as I increase the number of tables to be processed, the MERGE code is getting unwieldy.  To simplify, my idea is to create a script that will get the table names into a cursor, get the field names for that table into a different cursor, then compare temp and prod values.  If different, I will update the prod table.

The table 'TableManifest' has only 1 column called TableName.

So 2 questions

1 - Is this an efficient approach to the problem?  I'd love to get other suggestions.

2 - This code fails with an error "Must declare the table variable @Temp_TableName" on the line that starts with 'IF(SELECT..'.

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(MAX) -- TARGET Table to update
DECLARE @Temp_TableName varchar(MAX) -- SOURCE Table for compare
DECLARE @ColumnNames varchar(MAX) -- Table Column to compare

-- Create CURSOR of Tables to process
DECLARE C_TableNames CURSOR FOR SELECT TableName FROM TableManifest
OPEN C_TableNames

-- Get 1st table name
FETCH NEXT FROM C_TableNames INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    -- Create variable for TEMP table name
    SELECT @Temp_TableName = CONCAT('TEMP_',@TableName)
    
    -- Create CURSOR of Column Names in the table
    DECLARE C_ColumnNames CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    OPEN C_ColumNames
    
    -- Get 1st column name
    FETCH NEXT FROM C_ColumnNames INTO @ColumnNames
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
        -- If the column name is not 'ID' and the values are different, update the TARGET table    
        IF(SELECT @ColumnNames FROM @Temp_TableName) <> (SELECT @ColumnNames FROM @TableName) AND @ColumnNames <> 'id'
          UPDATE @TableName SET @ColumnNames = (SELECT @ColumnNames from @Temp_TableName)
        -- Get next column name
        FETCH NEXT FROM C_ColumnNames INTO @ColumnNames
      END
    -- Get next table name
    FETCH NEXT FROM C_TableNames INTO @TableName
  END

-- Clean up
CLOSE C_ColumNames
DEALLOCATE C_ColumNames
CLOSE C_TableNames
DEALLOCATE C_TableNames
```

Comment: That SQL wouldn't work as you already experienced. The error message you got is not important, even if you pass that one, even if you might succeed to write a correct syntax it wouldn't work. You are asking with a code that you think is the solution rather than your actual problem and that is called an XY problem.

Comment: Probably it would be easier if you just do the update from your temp tables (in a transaction maybe) without the likely unnecessary checking of column values. (BTW be careful about MERGE and prefer a script without it, it has some known problems).

Comment: Thanks, I see your point about the update transaction.  But I would still like the have the code loop through each table named in the 'TableManifest' table.

Comment: You would have to substitute _dynamic SQL_ for _wishful thinking_. SQL doesn't involve looking into variable values and guessing what might be interesting to process in new ways, e.g. `declare @Ill as NVarChar(1000) = N'cancer'; select CureFor@Ill;`. Writing and maintaining the code to do what is needed is probably a better idea than going down the dynamic SQL rabbit hole.

Comment: Tip: If you do use dynamic SQL the best practice when assembling object names into statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Probably you didn't really understand what I am saying. Could you even make a bit of this code work, writing the field names and table name? IOW, before using variables check if you can write it without variables at all. Otherwise it might be as simple as using sp_executesql.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with sp_executesql.  I have now is a procedure that uses the MERGE command on each table needing update. That means as I add more tables, I need to add more MERGE commands, adding lots of lines to the procedure.  Hoped to write a block of code that gets table names then gets the column list for that table and does the update.  If you can put up a small example then that would help.   I am also considering deleting the rows in the prod table and simply importing the entire temp table, replacing all the rows.  That seemed a bit clunky to me, but maybe I'm over thinking it.

Comment: You can start with [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). There you'll find `sysname`, a data type you ought to use.